# Vim Autocompletion. How to remove vertical side line and preview window?

Tags: vim, plugins, autocomplete

I installed YouCompleteMe vim plugin for autocompletion. It works well. However, during autocompletion I get a white column on the left side. You can see it in the attached picture. It has red ">>" symbols. Also, I have a preview window on the top. I want to get rid of them.
I added next lines to my .vimrc file

```
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
```

However, I still see preview window upon hitting Tab and the side paned still shows up.
How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: It looks like "let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0" disables the side panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>>` symbols are not exactly related to autocompletion; they're compilation error markers. To get rid of them, use:

```
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0
```

Preview window is controlled by Vim's 'completeopt' option. To disable it, use:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```